# Binding MaxValue property in DataBarFormatCondition issue

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, devexpress, gridcontrol

I'm implementing a `DataGrid` with the `DevExpress GridControl`. 
I have a property named `Bought` in my `ItemsSource` of the `GridControl`, implemented as below.

```
            <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Bought" 
                            Name="BoughtColumn"
                            MinWidth="60" Width="100"  
                            Header="Bought" />                  
            </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
```

To visualize this column I've been trying to use the `DataBarFormatCondition`. However, as per default, the `MaxValue` of the `DataBarFormatCondition` becomes the maximum value of `Bought` in the entire Column. Instead of having the `MaxValue` set as per default I'd like to use another property named `TotalActivity` as `MaxValue`. I've tried to bind it in various way but non of the bindings I have tried seem to work. Below is code for the `Binding` and how it visualizes.

```
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView AllowConditionalFormattingMenu="True">
                <dxg:TableView.FormatConditions>
                    <dxg:DataBarFormatCondition FieldName="Bought" PredefinedFormatName="BlueGradientDataBar" MaxValue="{Binding ElementName=BoughtColumn, Path=DataContext.RowData.Row.TotalActivity}"/>
                </dxg:TableView.FormatConditions>
            </dxg:TableView>
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
```

[image]

Big thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

You should define the [Expression property](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridFormatConditionBase_Expressiontopic):

```
<dxg:TableView.FormatConditions>
    <dxg:DataBarFormatCondition FieldName="Value" 
                                PredefinedFormatName="BlueGradientDataBar" />
    <dxg:DataBarFormatCondition FieldName="Id" Expression="[Value]" 
                                PredefinedFormatName="RedGradientDataBar" />
</dxg:TableView.FormatConditions>
```

[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIemt.png)